# How to use JPQL join on unidirectional one to many relationship

Tags: jpa, jpql, entitymanager

Here are my entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    //...
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Author author;

    //...
}
```

I don't want to declare the `Set<Book> books` field in the `Author` entity to avoid unnecessary data fetch. I already know about `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, but I have some cases in which even the lazy fetching is triggered.

Here is my question: How can I use JPQL join to retrieve the relationship in a custom query?
Look at `??books??` in the below query:

```java
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new " + AuthorWithBooks.class.getName() +
                "(a.id, ..., group_concat(b.name)) FROM Author a LEFT JOIN a.??books?? b GROUP BY a.id", AuthorWithBooks.class);
```

You should consider that there might be some `Author` with no book and I want to include them in my query! So I can not start my `join` from `Book`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch the from and join clause:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new " + AuthorWithBooks.class.getName() +
            "(a.id, ..., group_concat(b.name)) FROM Book b " + 
            "RIGHT JOIN b.author a GROUP BY a.id", AuthorWithBooks.class);
```

Comment: Note what I've mentioned in the last paragraph. I already know about this solution of yours. According to what I've said your solution must be changed to something like this: `"SELECT new " + AuthorWithBooks.class.getName() + "(a.id, ..., group_concat(b.name)) FROM Book b RIGHT JOIN b.author a GROUP BY a.id"`. But I'm not able to use `RIGHT` like the native SQL in order to acquire all of the authors in the result

Comment: Checkout my answer. Simply use RIGHT instead of LEFT in that case